# Search function that provides synonyms in results or provides corrections

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search, multilingual

I'll start with that I have no idea what would be the proper keywords to find this, therefore, please excuse me for, probably, misleading title and/or repeated question.

For example, when you search "potat" in google, it automaticly points you to potato. How could I achieve this in my application?

Nuance: it has to be multilingual, since application is primary oriented for non-English people.

Thanks in advance!

## Edit:

Uhm, are there any alternatives or anything to Sphinx? Because it looks like on the destination server where the application will be hosted when published, they won't have it.

Comment: Do you have a limited subset of content to search? 'cause if so, a simple auto-complete wordlist could do. If not, you may be in luck & find a free dictionary, but usually you'll have to pay for a dictionary in a usable digital format.

Comment: Nah, auto-complete won't cut it this time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there's a fine library called [sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) that can be installed with mysql or it could run as a separated deamon, it includes an API for different languages (including php)

it will build indexes so 'potat','potato' and 'potatoes' would be treated as the same word.

And to do the "Did you mean.." it has an option when indexing the information that saves the list of words and their frequency on the documents, so you could as this list if no results are found

Good Luck

Comment: And what about multilingual support... For example, if I use a search term as "šķiple" would it treat "šķipele" as the same word?

Comment: it works too... i'm using it for a french search engine, and it works fine with utf8... i tell sphinx to transform each letter with accent to a normal letter, For exemple: é=>e, è=>e ê=>e.. in you case šķiple would be indexed into "skiple".. i've also installed a french libstemer to treat conjugations and plurals, and you could also manually tell sphinx that "šķiple" must be threated as "šķipele"

Answer (score 0):

you could try to take a look at mysql's [SOUNDS LIKE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#operator_sounds-like)- or [SOUNDEX()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex)-syntax, it seems to improve your search results, but this isn't usable for getting some kind of "did you mean ???"-suggestions.